# How to connect new react native app with production react native app

Tags: react-native

I wrote a new react native app from the scratch and want to upload the new app as a new version to the app store. What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: increase `versionCode` inside the file `android/app/build.gradle` and build apk and publish it to the app store for more info see here https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this you must have previous keystore file for Android and apple certificates for iOS of the app. Added these things and create new builds of the app with the increased version. Then just simply go to the App Store and Play Store and upload your new build to the same app as newer version

Answer (score 0):

Shubham and Muhammad are correct.

Your React Native app behaves exactly like a native app once you build your apk.

Just make sure you use ***the exact same signing key*** and ***increase versionCode*** as you would for an update.

If you're still uncertain, here's a quick way to test that:

- Install your old app version on your phone.
- Generate a signed apk for your new app with increased version code
- Try to install that apk manually on your phone
- If your update is correct, your app should update correctly.